# Detecting chatter on a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

I have a VF page which uses standard controller (custom object). Basically I am overriding view action for a custom object. Now I have a section on this page which I want to show only if chatter is enabled for this object. Is there any way to check that? Any thought?

Answer (score 2):

[Enable or check Chatter Feed Tracking programatically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/enable-or-check-chatter-feed-tracking-programatically)

Read through this earlier discussions and also the schemadescribe call

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm

IsFeedenabled method for each object will tell you whether chatter is enabled or not for the object

Comment: can't we detect on VF page itself?

Answer (score 2):

See [Describe API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) - the `isFeedEnabled` method is what you're looking for. You'll need to put the logic in a custom controller extension, but it will only be a few lines.