# Track Activities value for a custom object

Tags: force.com, sobject, beta-managed-package, managed-package

I have a custom object.  I enable Track Activities for this custom object and then I create a managed beta.  If this managed beta is installed in a new org, the track activities will be enabled for the custom object.

If this managed beta is taken as an upgrade to an existing org, where the track activities for the same object is disabled it will still be disabled post install.

It is important the track activities is enabled, so I was hoping for a way in which this would be done and the user would not have to worry about doing it manually.

Is there any way it could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Post install script?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the following post would apply to your question: [Enable or check Chatter Feed Tracking programatically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/enable-or-check-chatter-feed-tracking-programatically). As there's also a limit on the number of objects that an organization can track the history on, normally 20 fields/object, I'd think that would be a very good reason for the org to have to enable the tracking (I understand that SF will increase it to between 40 - 50 if asked nicely $$$). The admin may need to choose which objects are going to be tracked and disable tracking on another object in order to support your custom object.